# Why is my view not loading correctly in Laravel when other pages are loading fine?

Tags: php, laravel

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','Admin']], function () {
    ...
    Route::get('/foo/fp',['uses' => 'ProgramReportController@getFp', 'as' => 'foo.getfp']);
});
```

ProgramReportController.php

```
class ProgramReportController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function getFp() {
        $data = Fpchart::select('*')->get()->toArray();
        $data = json_encode($data);

        return  view('foo.fp',compact('data'));
    }
}
```

foo\fp.php

```
@extends('layouts.foo')
@section('content')
<script>
    var data = {!!$data!!};
    console.log(data);
</script>
@endsection
```

layouts\foo.blade.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Foo</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <script src="{{asset('js/custom.js')}}"></script>
    <link href="{{asset('css/styles.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">
            <strong style="font-size: 78%;">
                <a href="#">ABOUT</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="#">PRIVACY</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="#">TERMS</a>
                <div class="pull-right">© 2020 FOO</div>
            </strong>
        </span>
      </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm only getting a white page and when I go to localhost:8000/foo/fp and the layout isn't loading. All I'm seeing in the page is this...

```
@extends('layouts.ched') @section('content') @endsection
```

And I'm getting this error in my console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!' on line 4 in fp.php
```

I tried every way of clearing my cache

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

but to no avail, nothing happened. When I go to other pages under the admin middleware, the pages are loading fine except for this, so I thought maybe that it's a cache problem but I've tried everything.

Comment: do you have layout file `views/layouts/foo.blade.php` .?

Comment: yes, other of my pages are using that same layout and they work perfectly fine expect for this fp.php

Comment: Have you got a folder called "foo" in your webroot?

Comment: add code of `foo.blade.php` then

Comment: yes as I've said, other pages are using this same layout without issues and I don't think the problem lies in foo.blade.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use blade directives in `.blade.php` files:

Rename `fp.php` to `fp.blade.php` and that should work

Comment: Good catch, didn't spot that.

Comment: Great catch lol i didn't notice that either so dumb of me hahaha thanks!